# Export WMI Results to CSV

Tags: logging, wmi

I'm trying to run a WMI command that retrieves MISSING systems software updates. I would like to export these results to a csv but I don't seem to be making much headway.. Help!

```
Wmic /output:P:\LOG\WMI.csv /namespace:\\root\ccm\softwareupdates\updatesstore path CCM_UpdateStatus get status, Article, Bulletin, UniqueId get /all /format:csv
```

Comment: `Wmic /output:"P:\LOG\WMI.csv" … ,UniqueId /all /format:csv` (note quoted filename in `/output` parameter *and* removed the last `get`) should  clear syntax errors.

Comment: So I modified the command but the data displays in one cell vs being deliminated.     Wmic /output:"c:\WMI.csv" /namespace:\\root\ccm\softwareupdates\updatesstore path CCM_UpdateStatus get status, Article, Bulletin, UniqueId /format:csv

Comment: ex: 121405-X1CARBON,4462209,,Missing,1b0aa3c7-67fe-4bb4-9c34-61024aae4fe8

Comment: Better late than never: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. Please feel free to [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (rather than elaborating it in a comment).

Comment: Sorry, I can't check wmic against `CCM_UpdateStatus` however such a query produces desired output using other `/namespace`, `path` and appropriate property list. Note that the output file is encoded `UCS-2 BOM` ([UTF 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16)).

Comment: I can identify comma-delimited output in your example. The columns listed in the query are preceded with (implicit) `Node` property (a machine_id, supposedly the same as `%computername%` if not specified).

Comment: @JosefZ, as an aside: As the Wikipedia article you linked to states, UCS-2 is _not_ the same as UTF-16: the former is a _fixed-width_ 2-byte encoding that covers the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane) subset of Unicode characters only, whereas the latter - _evolved_ from UCS-2 -  is a _variable-width_ encoding capable of encoding _all_ Unicode characters, which uses _pairs_ of 2-byte sequences to represent characters outside the BMP.